# get next/previous post name

Tags: posts, pages, previous, next

i know that : `<?php $pagename = get_query_var('name'); ?>` get the name of the current page/post. But I dont know how to get the name of the next and the previous post. I will use it for a hover tip and the alt of the image that will lead to the previous/next post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$prev = get_previous_post();
$next = get_next_post();
$prev_title = $prev ? get_the_title($prev) : 'Current is First Post';
$next_title = $next ? get_the_title($next) : 'Current is Last Post';
```

See [get_previous_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post) and [get_next_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post) on Codex for some details and additional params you can use.

Comment: it work, but please explain me the notation ... i dont know this short way of writing php... please make the long version so i can learn... thanks

Comment: `$prev_title = $prev ? get_the_title($prev) : 'Current is First Post';` is the same of `if ($prev) $prev_title = get_the_title($prev); else $prev_title = 'Current is First Post';` For more info see, e. g. [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/using-the-ternary-operator/).